# Using sql.NullFloat64 vs *float64 in Golang?

Tags: go

I'm using `gorm` to define my db table schema.  Noticed that `gorm` itself uses `time.Time` for `created_at` and `*time.Time` for `deleted_at`.  I'm assuming this is because `deleted_at` has cases of being `NULL`.

I also noticed that for many Golang ORMs they use `sql.NullFloat64` for storing db values that could be a `float64` or `NULL`.  Why not just use `*float64` instead of `sql.NullFloat64`? What's the difference?

```
type Geo struct {
    latitude *float64
    longitude sql.NullFloat64
}
// What is the difference between latitude and longitude in this case?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Russ Cox](https://github.com/rsc) (biggest Go's contributor according to Github) : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/vOTFu2SMNeA

> There's no effective difference. We thought people might want to use NullString because it is so common and perhaps expresses the intent more clearly than *string. But either will work.

I'm thinking though that using a pointer might give the GC one more thing to track. It probably depends on the usage.

On some very simple code, using `-gcflags=-m` to build, the escape analysis does say that `new(float64) escapes to heap` (here is the dummy code I used: https://play.golang.org/p/K4sQaXyQKG).

Also, when debugging, printing a struct containing a `sql.NullSomething` (`{value:{Float64:1 Valid:true}}`) looks better than a struct containing a pointer (`{value:0xc82000a420}`).

So I'd recommend the usage of the `sql.Null*` structs.